# Xcode Call Web PHP File with parameters?

Tags: objective-c, mknetworkkit

I have been working on networking my ios app. I need to call a php file on my website and then get information back. I have been using this tutorial but it is out of date and unsupported now.

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service
```

I have been looking at the MKNetworkKit for a bit and i think that is what i need to use but i am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people agree that [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) is the best suited library for this. There's even a really nice [raywenderlich.com tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course) on how to use it.

For instance, I use it this way to get the contents of a link with parameters (makemyday.com/web/export.php?id=345) into a `UIWebView`:

```
- (IBAction)searchForNearbyButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://makemyday.com"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"id": @"345"};
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [client getPath:@"/web/export.php"
         parameters:parameters
            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"response=%@", [operation.response allHeaderFields]);
                [self.webView loadData:responseObject  MIMEType:operation.response.MIMEType textEncodingName:operation.response.textEncodingName baseURL:operation.response.URL];
            }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error=%@", error.description);
            }
     ];

}
```

Comment: Awesome looks good, just another question in php does it return what I have it echo?

Comment: You can examine the response this way:                `NSLog(@"responseObject=%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` (if the conent is UTF-8 encoded)

Comment: @user511 When you recommend a library against that one the OP is planing to use, it would have been fair to mention that MKNetworkKit can achieve the same network related tasks. And I'm sure, with less potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Type in "NSURLConnection" into help. Some good examples there.

The easiest is doing a synchronous call with NSURLConnection.

Which is a blocking call until your server responds and closes.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://makemyday.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Better methods for user experience are asynch using a delegate. I found the following satisfying, since one can add a time out of 5, 10, 20, 60 seconds whatever.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:**20.0**];

NSURLDownload  *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:**self**]; // NOTE THE SELF FOR THE CALLBACks

if (!theDownload) {
   //OOPS
}
```

That use the following callback methods for fail, success/finish and filename

```
- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:(NSString *)filename;
- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)downloadDidFinish:(NSURLDownload *)download;
- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didCreateDestination:(NSString *)path
```